# Writing strings on files in ISO C89

Tags: c, string, file, loops, ansi-c

I have to write a string on a file,an address like : "Via Leopardi 38".
I think that a loop and a char by char printing is the best system,because it has no problems related to the non-null terminated strings.
The problem is that when the loop arrives to the null char(the space between "Via" and "Leopardi" the loop ends and  it writes only "Via".
Is there a different test condition for the loop I could use?

```
FILE *fo = open(filename,"w");

for (j=0;isalnum(phonebook[i].addr[j])!=0;j++) {


 fprintf(fo,"%c",phonebook[i].addr[j]);

}
```

Comment: Do you really use null char between "Via" and "Leopardi"? Isn't it normal whitespace (ASCII 0x20)?

Comment: I apologize,I made a stupid mistake,I was talking about the whitespace when you press the spacebar button on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace is not alphabet nor digits, so `isalnum(phonebook[i].addr[j])` will return `0` and tle loop ends.

Try using `phonebook[i].addr[j]!=0` as the condition.

Comment: It writes : "via leopardi 38ÍÍÍÍÍ".
It should write "via leopardi".
I don't know why.

Comment: You are testing with isalnum() which accepts both letters and digits.  You seem to be asking for just letters, which is the isalpha() test.  If you need to avoid trailing spaces you also need to either test for them after the loop ends or defer adding them until you detect at least one more valid letter,

Comment: @Luke: so is your `addr` a properly zero-terminated C string? Or is it an array of some fixed size - and filled entirely? What do you see when you simply `printf` it?

Comment: Well,it is a string,with a maximum size of 20,which belongs to a struct "contact" as well as similar name,surname and number strings.When I printf it I see "via leopardi 38" with no issues at all.My teacher doesn't want the strings to be case-sensitive,so I have to lower them with a to lower char by char assignment.My teacher gave me the main.c,I have to develop only the library function that his functions,that use the damn curses library,are going to use.